# Constructor return value

Tags: c++, constructor

Could you tell me what is wrong with my class constructor?
Code:

```
CVector::CVector (int size_)
{
    if (size_ > 0)
    {
        this->size = size_;
        this->data = new double[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        { 
            (*this)(i) = i;
        }
     }
     cout << "constructor end" << endl;
     return;
}
```

Usage example:

```
tvector = CVector(6);
```

I get an access violation after `"constructor end"` output.

**Update**: 
Constructor call was incorrect.
Using

`CVector tvector(6);`
worked.

Comment: Any reason not to use `std::vector`?

Comment: Please post the full declaration of `CVector`, which helps to resolve the members `size`, `data` and any other mysterious methods and members not explained in your fragment.

Comment: Please read up on _initialization lists_, which is what you should be using to initialize your data members.

Comment: Also, though this isn't your problem here, this constructor doesn't initialize anything if _size<=0 - are you sure this is what you want?  I can't see how the destructor could avoid producing undefined behaviour when you destroy an object with _size<=0 (unless you leak the memory you allocate when _size>0)

Comment: @Ivan: Even though you have it "fixed", please don't disregard the comments people have made as you continue. There are lots of problems with the code.

Comment: @GMan - Save the Unicorns I know about that and try to fix them, but it is my first project in C++ so it's obvious there would be lots of mistakes. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you want: `this->data[i] = i`;

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you didn't add a copy constructor and the destructor frees some memory that you happened to stomp on with some other code.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `return` statement at the end of a constructor's body.

Constructors do return a value, but that is a more detailed explanation for another time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by

```
(*this)(i) = i;
```

you actually meant

```
this->data[i] = i;
```

Right?

Comment: Yes, basicallt it is the same. I have implemented operator() to access data[].

Comment: @Ivan: There is no operator() in the code you posted.  Perhaps you didn't post your entire class?